# How to Check if Your elementary System Is 32-bit or 64-bit

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit

I want to remove Elementary OS and want to get back to Windows but to install Windows i need to identity if 32-bit architecture or 64-bit architecture
and whet I open details about my current system - there is no details about it.
How to find it out?

Answer (score 2):

Elementary is 64 bit only and has been for a while. However, you can check your CPU's abilities with:

```
sudo lshw -class processor
```

That will give you a bunch of information about your CPU. You can look specifically for:

> width: 64 bits